# phonegap window.location not working with .html#page

Tags: javascript, jquery, cordova, jquery-mobile

At first sorry if i have some typing errors english is not my main language but i try to do my best to explain it at my best.

I am working on a test app with a note database.
It works fine with adding and deleting but there is a small problem...
At the moment that i add a note (on edit.html) and want to go back to the index.html page it is not going back.
i am working with multiple data-page-role pages so each page has his own id.
The code that i use for the note database:

index.html Header:

```
$("#homePage").live('pageinit', function() {
init();
});
```

index.html data-page-role

```
<div data-role="page" id="homePage" data-add-back-btn="true" class="noteclass">
<!-- HEader -->
<div data-role="header" >
    <h1>Notitie Database</h1>
</div>
<!-- Main content div -->
<div data-role="content" id="mainContent">
    <ul data-role="listview" id="noteTitleList"></ul><br />
</div>
<div data-role="content">
    <a href="edit.html" data-role="button" data-icon="plus">Voeg notitie toe</a>
</div>
<!-- Footer -->
<div data-role="footer" id="footer"> <img src="a12.png" />
    <p>&copy; 2012 - Swen Kooij / Paksha Thullner / Johnny Jansen</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Edit.html (here u can add/change/remove the notes)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
</head>
<body>
<div data-role="page" id="editPage">
<!-- HEader -->
<div data-role="header">
    <h1>Write Note</h1>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#Delete').click(function() {
        DeleteNote($('#noteId').val());
    });

    $('#addNote').click(function() {
        var data = {title:$("#noteTitle").val(), 
                body:$("#noteBody").val(),
                id:$("#noteId").val()
        };
        saveNote(data);             
    });     
});
</script>
<div data-role="content">   
    <form id="editNoteForm" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="noteId" id="noteId" value="">
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="noteTitle">Title</label>
            <input type="text" name="noteTitle" id="noteTitle">
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <label for="noteBody">Note</label>
            <textarea name="noteBody" id="noteBody"></textarea>
        </div>
        <div data-role="fieldcontain">
            <button id="addNote">Opslaan</button>
        </div>
    </form>
    <button id="Delete">Verwijder</button>
</div>
<a href="index.html#homePage" data-role="button" data-icon="home">Ga terug</a>
<!-- Footer -->
<div data-role="footer" id="footer"> <img src="a12.png" />
    <p>&copy; 2012 - Swen Kooij / Paksha Thullner / Johnny Jansen</p>
</div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

And here is the backend code that i use for the note database

```
document.addEventListener("deviceready", onDeviceReady, false);

function onDeviceReady() {
phoneready();
}

function setupTable(tx){
tx.executeSql("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS notes(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,title,body,updated)");
}   

function getEntries() {
dbShell.transaction(function(tx)
{
    tx.executeSql("select id,title,body, updated from notes order by id asc", dbErrorHandler, renderEntries)
}, function(){ alert ("Error getentries"); 
});

}


function renderEntries(tx,results){
if (results.rows.length == 0) {
    $("#mainContent").html("<p>Je hebt nog geen notities.</p>");
} else {
   var s = "";
   for(var i=0; i<results.rows.length; i++) {
     s += "<li><a href='edit.html?id="+results.rows.item(i).id + "'>" + results.rows.item(i).title + "</a></li>";   
   }
   $("#noteTitleList").html(s);
   $("#noteTitleList").listview("refresh");
}
}

function saveNote(note) {

//Sometimes you may want to jot down something quickly....
if(note.title == "") note.title = "[Geen Titel]";
dbShell.transaction(function(tx) {
    if(note.id == "") 
    {
        tx.executeSql("insert into notes(title,body,updated) values(?,?,?)",[note.title,note.body, new Date()]);
    }
    else
    {
         tx.executeSql("update notes set title=?, body=?, updated=? where id=?",[note.title,note.body, new Date(), note.id]);
    }
}, function(){ alert ("Error savenote");}, 
    function()
    {
        window.navigator.location("index.html#homePage");
    });
}

function DeleteNote(id){
    dbShell.transaction(
    function(tx)
    {
        tx.executeSql('Delete FROM notes where id=' + id);
    },
        function(){ alert ("Error deletenote");},
    function(err)
    {
        window.navigator.location("index.html#homePage");
    });
}

function phoneready(){
dbShell = window.openDatabase("SimpleNotes", 2, "SimpleNotes", 1000000);
setupTable();   
}

function init(){
getEntries();

//edit page logic needs to know to get old record (possible)
$("#editPage").live("pagebeforeshow", function() {
    //get the location - it is a hash - got to be a better way
    var loc = window.location.hash;
    if(loc.indexOf("?") >= 0) {
        var qs = loc.substr(loc.indexOf("?")+1,loc.length);
        var noteId = qs.split("=")[1];
        //load the values
        dbShell.transaction(
            function(tx) {
                tx.executeSql("select id,title,body from notes where id=?",[noteId],function(tx,results) {
                    $("#noteId").val(results.rows.item(0).id);
                    $("#noteTitle").val(results.rows.item(0).title);
                    $("#noteBody").val(results.rows.item(0).body);
                });
            }, dbErrorHandler);

    }
});
}
```

As u can see at saveNote and on deleteNote i call the function window.navigator.location("index.html#homePage");
I did this as far as i tried with $.mobile.changePage("index.html#homePage"); it will go back but then it won't run the init(); function at the header script.
I hope i explained it all correct and if there are any questions please let me know.
I will try then to do my best at explaining it.

edit:
More information:

At first thank you for your answer, i got multiple data-role-pages.

A extra example:

```
<div data-role="page" id="page5" data-add-back-btn="true">
<!-- Header --> 
<div data-role="header" >
<h1>Locatie</h1>
</div>
<!-- Main content div -->
<div data-role="content">   
<p id="geolocation" onClick="onDeviceReady()">Op zoek naar uw locatie ...</p>
<img src="" id="map" width="100%" height="" />
<h4>Omgeving</h4>
<img src="" id="map2" width="100%" height="" />
</div>
<div data-role="footer" id="footer"> <img src="a12.png" />
<p>&copy; 2012 -  Swen Kooij / Paksha Thullner / Johnny Jansen</p>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to change page with deep link "index.html#homePage" .
JqueryMobile does not support that. When you pass a file, he will load ONLY the first page of that file.
This means that when you pass "index.html#homePage", he'll only consider the "index.html" and load the first page on that file.

I don't know it for sure, but if in your index.html file only have the "homePage", change function window.navigator.location to:

```
$.mobile.changePage("index.html")
```

And of course do the same for the anchor tag .

Comment: change the window.navigator.location to changePage, because the first does not work

Comment: Just made a edit to the first post. I got multiple "anchor" pages in my index.html, wanted to type that to but my laptop battery was out of battery. If there is no other way i will just lead it to the index.html instead of the anchor page. Preferring the anchor page but if i have no other choice i will do it the other way

Comment: forget about the "anchor" thing. The name for what you're using in index.html is Multiplate page template. In this case you have multiple pages in one file and other files with one page right? That will be a problem because when you try to go back to index.html he'll only load the first page.

Comment: Ok i changed it like u said, but now at the moment as soon as i go back (After removing a note) it won't update the main page. I got to kill the app before i can see the changes in there. Do u got any solution for that ? I tried pagebeforeshow but that didnt work

Comment: The refreshing stuff you should take care using the page events(pageinit,pageshow, pagebeforeshow and so on). In my case when it goes back to the "main" page, data is refreshed using the "pagebeforeshow" event. Make sure these events are happening with some debug

Comment: Weird cause as soon as i add a note. It should be saved but as soon as i hit the "Ga Terug" (Translated: Go Back) button it still not updating the list :( Adding debug alerts now.
Also thank you for your help so far :)

Comment: Ok call me crazy but i think it is working now.
Thank you for all your help, i hope it will keep on working now without any trouble. Realy thank you !!!!!

Answer (score 0):

I use:

window.location = "#home";